# Adding infinity value to an array

Tags: java, arrays, infinity

I want to add an infinity value to the last index of an array. I tried something like this in my java code. My array is an integer type.

```
Integer myInf = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
array_name[length_of_array]=myInf;
```

It is not working. What might be the problem in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: it said ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is not an infinity value

Answer (score 3):

Use one less index value in array_name.

```
Integer myInf = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
array_name[length_of_array - 1]=myInf;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `length_of_array` set to the correct value? Also, arrays are 0-indexed, so the last index is 1 less than the size of the array.

Try this instead:

```
array_name[array_name.length - 1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```